# Incompatible type for argument 1 of 'bezierPathWithOvalInRect' error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, appkit

I have the following code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect 
{
   [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:[self theRect]] stroke];
}

- (NSRect)theRect
{
   return NSMakeRect(1, 1, 1, 1); // made up some values
}
```

When I compile it says "Incompatible type for argument 1 of 'bezierPathWithOvalInRect' error". When I do this, however, it works:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect 
{
   NSRect theRect = NSMakeRect(1, 1, 1, 1);
   [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:theRect] stroke];
}
```

What is problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you put `- (NSRect)theRect` in your header?

Also does it say your program might not respond to `-theRect`?

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that I didn't declare it in the header file.